# Saving multiple 2D numpy arrays as greyvalue images

Tags: python

Starting from a numpy array A with size [365,365,20], I want to save each slice A[:,:,i] as a '.bmp' grey scale image. The matrix A exists of elements with **int values** between 0 and 32. It is essential that the grey values don't vary between images. So, each **int values** in the numpy array should be visualized as one specific grey value in all images.

I tried this using imageio (see code below), however, I observed that the grey values were different between images for the same **int value**. So, an **int value** of 15 was visualized in one image with light grey and in another in dark grey.

Therefore, is it possible to set grey values yourself using imagio or is there another way to make sure that the grey values correspond with the **int values** in the slice?

```
number_of_slices = A.shape[2] 
for count range(number_of_slices):
    Slice = A[:,:,count]
    Name = "Slices%s"%(count)+".bmp" 
    imageio.imwrite(Name,Slice)
```

Comment: What shape do you expect each output to be? `(365, 365, 3)`?

Comment: Your image will scale along the greyscale based on the maximum intensity of the numpy array you specify, so if one slice only goes up to 15 it will treat 15 as black, another frame going to 32 will treat 32 as black.  I don't really know `imageio` but it should have a format (try `imageio.help()`) that will take a specified max.  Otherwise you could add a reference pixel, or border all at 32 so that each frame has the same max.

Comment: My output should be an image of shape (365,365)

Comment: @user11346222 You mean 20 images, each of shape `(365, 365)`, right?

Comment: Finally, I obtained the wanted result by adding in each slice the minimum and maximum value of the complete (365,365,20) matrix

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np

minimum = data.min()
maximum = data.max()

rescaled = A * 255 / (maximum - minimum)

result = [image for image in np.rollaxis(rescaled, 2)]
```